# Javascript script timer issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a count down timer. I manage to make one but the problem with this is it stops when I close browser. So when user revisit my site it restart again. What I want is to keep that timer. *For example, if user leaves my site at timer 22:14:09. So timer will continue. Lets say the user revisits my site after an hour so the time should be 21:14:09.*  How can I do that?

Here is my JS

```
$(function () {
var hrs, mins, secs, TimerRunning, TimerID,
    Timer = {
        init: function () {
            hrs          = 23;
            mins         = 59;
            secs         = 59;
            TimerRunning = false;
            Timer.StopTimer();
            Timer.StartTimer();
         },

         StopTimer: function () {
            if(TimerRunning)
               clearTimeout(TimerID);
            TimerRunning=false;
         },

         StartTimer: function () {
            TimerRunning = true;
            $('.timer').html(Timer.Pad(hrs) + ":" + Timer.Pad(mins) + ":" + Timer.Pad(secs));
            TimerID = self.setInterval("StartTimer()", 1000);

            if(hrs == 0 && mins == 0 && secs == 0)
               StopTimer();

            if (secs == 0) {
               mins--;
               secs = 59;
            }
            if (mins == 0) {
                hrs--;
                mins = 59;
            }
            secs--;
            setTimeout(function () { Timer.StartTimer(); }, 1000);
         },

         Pad: function (number) {
            if(number < 10)
               number = 0+""+number;
            return number;
         }

    };

Timer.init();
});
```

**Update**

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TH2fp/)

Comment: Move the timer to the server side.

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer a bit?

Comment: No need any serverside here. Just set the cookie on page unload.

Comment: Please see my updates post which is in italic. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for this problem.

```
// use hours, minutes & seconds to set time limit
var hours = 1, 
    minutes = 30, 
    seconds = 0,
    maxTime =  ( ( hours * 3600 ) + ( minutes * 60 ) + seconds ) * 1000,
    // if timeleft not in localStorage then default to maxTime
    timeLeft = ( localStorage.timeLeft || maxTime ),
    startTime = new Date(),
    intervalRef;

// check if user has already used up time
if( timeLeft > 0 ) {

    intervalRef = setInterval( setTimeLeft, 5000 );
} else {

    stopTrackingTime();
}

function setTimeLeft( ) {

    // if user has used up time exit
    if( localStorage.timeLeft < 0 ) {

        stopTrackingTime();
    }

    // calculate how long user has left
    var elapsed = ( new Date() - startTime );
    localStorage.timeLeft = timeLeft - elapsed;
};

// function called once user has used up time
function stopTrackingTime( ) {

    clearInterval( intervalRef );
    alert( "end of time allowed" );
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/TH2fp/28/)

Answer (score 0):

You could store the time in `LocalStorage`, and it would be persistent across browser restarts.

In your case something as simple as

```
localStorage["mytimer"] = JSON.stringify([hrs, mins, secs]);
```

should work for storage, and you could do

```
var previousTime = JSON.parse(localStorage["mytimer"]);
```

to retrieve the previous value.

You could read more about it here: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html.

Comment: Please see my updated post which is in italic. That is what I want

Comment: @al0ne just store time spent on the site in local storage rather than the current time. `localStorage["timeSpent"] = JSON.stringify( [hrsSpent, minsSpent, secsSpent])`

Comment: @Bruno I added these two lines but still it does not work the way I wanted `localStorage["mytimer"] = JSON.stringify([hrs, mins, secs]);
       var previousTime = JSON.parse(localStorage["mytimer"]);
       //$('.timer').html(Timer.Pad(hrs) + ":" + Timer.Pad(mins) + ":" + Timer.Pad(secs));
       $('.timer').html(previousTime);`

Comment: It still restarts from beginning.

Comment: Just be aware that using local storage (cookies, or html5 local storage) opens up your code to the possibility the timer data can be adjusted manually by the user.  If you are coding an exam or something else that requires security around your timer, do not use local storage.

Comment: @al0ne Created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GRkyt/3/) that writes value of timer in localStorage to the document. First time it will write to localStorage. On refresh it should write the value to the document. It does on my browser anyway. By the way, localStorage is not available in every browser as it is new HTML5 functionality.

Comment: @al0ne I have posted an answer. Have a look and check if it is suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your StartTimer function so that every time it is called a local time stamp (`new Date`) be saved in cookie or localStorage. Besides, the setTimeout isn't very reliable, your should adjust the time count with real time every now and then.